# No such file or directory '/dev/ttyACM0'

Tags: usb, pi-3b+

Hi im using the AWSgreengrass sdk on a Raspberry Pi 3 b+ to read some lora sensors that I made. If I use the arduino IDE, the raspberry can work without problems with the feather and in the serial monitor I can see what is reading. But, when im using the lambda function it gaves me the error.

the file /dev/ttyACM0 is with chmod 777 permissions

and I added pi,root and ggc_user to dialout, root and tty groups. But still with the same problem. The logs gave me this back

```
[ERROR]-lambda_function.py:20,[ERROR] - Error :Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]-  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
[ERROR]-    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
[ERROR]-FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
[ERROR]-During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[ERROR]-Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]-  File "/lambda/lambda_function.py", line 17, in <module>
[ERROR]-    mc.run()
[ERROR]-  File "/lambda/main_controller.py", line 24, in run
[ERROR]-    self.ser_controller.search_port()   # Search ober the serial port where write/read
[ERROR]-  File "/lambda/serial_controller.py", line 26, in search_port
[ERROR]-    ser = serial.Serial(self.port, self.baud, timeout=0.1)
[ERROR]-  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
[ERROR]-    self.open()
[ERROR]-  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
[ERROR]-    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
[ERROR]-serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you enabled the serial port in raspi-config - if not by default the console has it.  Also look at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19648/difference-between-dev-ttyacm0-and-dev-ttys0-arduino-ide-ports-under-linux#19649 and how Bluetooth makes a mess of names on the pi at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

Comment: Thanks @Andyroo Yes did it, I have actually solved this now. It was something about resources permissions by the AWS Lambda side. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

To access to local resources you need to add them by the AWS Lambda configuration side. In the AWS console.

But, is true that all the permissions must be set right in the Raspberry Pi first.

dialout and tty group access to the ggc_user
and serial port in raspi-config

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.